# Change cases of string multiple time in js?

Tags: javascript, case

I want to convert a set of characters in string from example in 'HeLLo' to small case example 'hello' and then back to the original string as in 'HeLLo' from the small case. Is there an algo to do this subrountine?

convert from "HeLLo" to this => "hello" and then back again to the original text "hello" => "HeLLo" only this step is required later on, not immediately.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp particularly the note about all/first occurrences

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code and describe what's not working.

Comment: Did you look at `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @SLaks, it looks like he wants to retain the original so that it can be reverted as well. I think this is bigger than `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Not, you know, *much* bigger.

Comment: @DanielBeck not much bigger, on the surface, but without a bit more context it's hard to give an answer. Quick answer, just store the old value in a variable. Ok, but now I need to store 10 of them.

Answer (score 0):

String is just set or characters and nothing else. It can't contain information about cases which you used in past.

But you can just invoke `String.toLowerCase` from your string and this invoke return to you new string and will not mutate your existing string.